Is the amount of blood money for a male child higher than an adult female?
I know that the blood money for women in Islam is considered half of a man, but does this apply for children to? If so, does this mean that a woman's blood money is less than a male child?

Yes.
The blood money for a child is equal to that of an adult, males to males and females to females. It is only the blood money for an unborn child which is lower.
Ref:

أجمع العلماء على أن ديات الرجال، شريفهم ووضيعهم سواء، إذا كانوا أحرارا مسلمين، وكذلك ذكور الصبيان في دياتهم كآبائهم، الطفل والشيخ في ذلك سواء، وكذلك الطفلة، كأمها في ديتها
— al-Tamhid - Ibn 'Abd al-Barr


is there a reason for this? Like is the blood money for a woman less than a boy because the male gender is better?
